# Using a checkbox to show entered values in a field to another field when a check box is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Html - Delivery address has to give the entered value to  billing address. The javascript and html are in separate files

Other js features are working fine, but its just this one that doesn't seem to work

```
<div class="textinput">
    <label for="deladdress">Delivery Address: </label>
    <input id="deladdress" type="text" name="Delivery Address" />
</div>
<div id="buttoncheckarea">
    <input id="CheckDelivery" type="checkbox" name="CheckDelivery">
    <label id="diff" for="CheckDelivery">Same as delivery address?</label>
</div>
<div class="textinput">
    <label for="postcode">Postcode: </label>
    <input id="postcode" type="text" name="postcode" />
</div>
<div class="textinput">
    <label for="billaddress">Billing Address: </label>
    <input id="billaddress" type="text" name="Billing Address" />
</div>
```

javascript

```
function deliveryfunc() {
    var delivery = document.getElementById("deladdress").value;
    var billing = document.getElementById("billaddress").value;
    //var checkbox = document.getElementById("CheckDelivery").checked;
    if (document.getElementsByName("CheckDelivery").checked == true) {      
        billing = delivery;
    }
}

function init () {  
    var order = document.getElementById("ordForm");
    order.onsubmit = ordervalidation;   
    order.onclick = radiobuttoncheck;
    var checkbutton = document.getElementsByName("CheckDelivery");
    checkbutton.onclick = deliveryfunc;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your `deliveryfunc` as below:

```
function deliveryfunc() {
   var delivery = document.getElementById("deladdress");
   var billing = document.getElementById("billaddress");
   if (document.getElementById("CheckDelivery").checked == true) {      
       billing.value = delivery.value;
   }
}

function init () {  
    var order = document.getElementById("ordForm");
    order.onsubmit = ordervalidation;   
    order.onclick = radiobuttoncheck;
    var checkbutton = document.getElementById("CheckDelivery");
    checkbutton.onclick = deliveryfunc;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: found the probelm, you were using `getElementsByName` which returns a collection [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp). By changing it to `getElementByName` code will work, updated the answer.

Comment: also you can use `document.getElementsByName("CheckDelivery")[0]` which will return first element with name `CheckDelivery`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! but i don't think <getElementByName> is a function, since it produces an error

Comment: Oops typo, should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementByName`.